# how to insert .img file into sd card in Ubuntu guest on Windows Host in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, sd-card

my configuration :

```
VirtualBox 5.12
Host Windows 10
Guest Ubuntu 16.04
```

Im trying to insert an .img file into and sd card on Ubuntu so that im able to boot on it.

I have tried two methods but none is working:

**1 - Accessing SD card from Ubuntu by creating .vmdk image and importing it in VirtualBox as SATA disk.**(https://scribles.net/accessing-sd-card-from-linux-virtualbox-guest-on-windows-host/) Here I am able to see the sd card in my ubuntu guest using *lsblk* command(it is shown as /dev/sdc). Then, I do

```
sudo dd if=xxx.img of=/dev/sdc bs=64M
```

The output shows that the image has been written with no errors. HOWEVER, the sd card remains empty ! so I move on to the next method

**2 - Sharing sd card using VBoxManage share folder.** I used this solution (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=60226) to share the sd card between Windows and Ubuntu. I now try this command:

```
sudo dd if=xxx.img of=/xx/sf_shared_sd_card bs=64
```

The output is dd: failed to open '/media/sf_shared_sd_card/': Is a directory

As far as I understood, *dd* works with disks and not directories, thus this second method fails unless I could somehow "mount" the shared directory as a disk in /dev for example, but im not sure if its possible ..

At this point im not sure what to try next, any suggestions please?

Comment: I remember VirtualBox has an option to pass-through USB devices to the VM. Would that work, using an USB SD-Card reader, passing it through to the VM and then work on that?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?